# GET https://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps, google-analytics

When I'm Accessing my Site with Google Maps, The Maps load so slow and then this error Shows up. `GET https://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Tried clearing my Cache and Browsing in Incognito Window but all show the same error

Tried in Other browser like Firefox but same error shows

Did someone encountered the same error before?

Please Help me , Thanks

Comment: It is probably blocked by an AdBlock extension or similar (e.g., Ghostery) if they also try to prevent tracking mechanisms (like GA). Though blocking GA should probably not influence the loading time of Maps. Do you still get the problem if you disable all your extensions? For example, when using [Firefox Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) ? If you can also not reach the `ga.js` by pasting that address in your address bar you might be blocking it some other way, like in your HOSTS file.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers my site is Https. do you think it is also one factor?

Comment: I don't think so. The client is downloading the `ga.js` file from Google's servers, not from your site. Did the Firefox Safe Mode do anything? What about an entirely different computer?

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers tried in Firefox Safe mode and works perfectly . .tried on my colleagues computer and same thing .  Lazy loading because of the error. now that i removed the script, it loads in 1 second

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, solved by disabling the HTTPS Everywhere browser extension, which I believe is forcing the downloading of the ga.js through https from where it is not necessarily available.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to Firewall blocking google-analytics.com